# Xamarin Forms ListView not displaying Text

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

for my app I want a very simple listview, so in my VS, I right click -> add new item -> List View Page. I didn't change anything in the .xaml or .cs

**ListView.xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

  <!--Built in Cells-->
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextCell />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**ListView.xaml.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    public FacilityListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4",
            "Item 5"
        };

        BindingContext = this;
    }

    async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        await DisplayAlert("Item Tapped", "An item was tapped.", "OK");

        //Deselect Item
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

The list shows only the cells, without text

[image: listview cells without text]

I tried changing the binding, adding textColor etc. but no matter what, the cells remain empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your template just contains an empty TextCell.  You have to use binding to tell it what to display

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, I did not think of that. I was so confused because I was assuming the template would work out of the box.